# How to create facebook app images for specific user

Tags: php, facebook, image, image-processing

Now a days there are lots of third-party facebook apps that keeps floating in the net so I though I might start a app. After setting up the PHP-SDK, I got all the information need like user's name, email, profile pic, but how can i create those awesome pictures that the app creates example
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9fsF.png)

So can anyone help me how to acheive this kind of things. I've tried lots of things like HTML2CANVAS but still doesn't help.

Thanks in Advance...